# Failed to inject Kafka client into GrpcService Quarkus

Tags: java, apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, grpc, quarkus

I'm trying to receive message through Grpc service, send it to Kafka Emitter, and return some value back.

```java
@Singleton
@GrpcService
public class MessageService implements protobuf.MessageService{

    @Inject
    @Channel("hello-out")
    Emitter<Record<String, GeneratedMessageV3>> emitter;

    @Override
    public Uni<EnvelopeReply> processMessage(Envelope request) {
        return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(
                emitter.send(Record.of(request.getKey(), request))
        ).replaceWith(EnvelopeReply.newBuilder().build());
    }
}
```

During build, I'm getting next error:

```
 Error injecting org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.messaging.Emitter<io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.kafka.Record<java.lang.String, com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3>> com.test.MessageService.emitter
...
Caused by: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DefinitionException: SRMSG00019: Unable to connect an emitter with the channel `hello-out`
```

It works properly with Rest resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without going deeply into the topic, here's my solution:
You can't inject Kafka Emmiter directly to grpc service, it'll throw an exception.

```
GrpcService <- Emitter<Record...>
```

Possible reason(I'm sure Quarkus team will reply lower with correct solution :)) is that all GrpcServices are of `@Singleton` type, and they can't have lazy-initialised properties, they need to have something directly injected. `Emitter` is generated at a later stage.
By adding a wrapper class you're solving all the headaches, so:

```
GrpcService <- KafkaService <- Emitter<Record...>
```

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class KafkaService {

    @Inject
    @Channel("hello-out")
    Emitter<Record<String, GeneratedMessageV3>> emitter;
    // Implement this part properly, added just for example
    public Emitter<Record<String, GeneratedMessageV3>> getEmitter() {
        return emitter;
    }

}
...
@Singleton
@GrpcService
public class MessageService implements protobuf.MessageService {

    @Inject
    KafkaService kafkaService;

    @Override
    public Uni<EnvelopeReply> processMessage(Envelope request) {
        // use metadata if needed
        Map<String, String> metadataMap = request.getMetadataMap();
        return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(
                kafkaService.getEmitter().send(Record.of(request.getKey(), request))
        ).replaceWith(EnvelopeReply.newBuilder().build());
    }
}
```